# Force a "condition" when saving a relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 for the first time to build a web application for a customer. I have two tables, `User` and `Zone`, with relationships between them.

In particular, this is (a simplified) `User`

```php
Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->enum('role', array('type1', 'type2', 'type3')->default('type1');
    $table->integer('zone_id')->nullable();
});
```

and this is `Zone`

```php
Schema::create('zones', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});
```

*Users* can have zero or one zones, this is why `zone_id` is nullable. However they can have one zone only if their `role` column has a value of `type2` or `type3`, and not if `role` is `type1`.

These are my models

```php
// models/User.php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function zone() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Zone');
    }

}

// models/Zone.php

class Zone extends Eloquent {

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }

}
```

I don't know how to add the `role` condition in the models.

Indeed, I'm writing a test which fails:

```php
class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function testUserInZoneMustHaveASpecificRole() {
        $zone = FactoryMuff::create('Zone');
        $user = FactoryMuff::create('User');

        // $user, by default has role == 'type1'

        // This should pass, because I shouldn't be able to
        // associate a role=='type1' user to a zone

        $this->assertFalse($zone->users()->save($user)->save());
    }
}
```

Can you give me some help? I'm facing this problem in many parts of the application, due to my customer requests.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it the Validation class that you need?  Check it out here: http://laravel.com/docs/validation

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'd like to do enforced constraints, which should always hold no matter if you run validation or not.

Comment: Validation can be applied whenever a change is being made: saving a new instance, or updating an existing instance.. you can "bake" it into the `Eloquent` class.. This is an excellent tutorial: http://daylerees.com/trick-validation-within-models

Comment: Nice tutorial, but I think it's not the solution I need. I'm forced to run the `validate()` method everytime I need validation; instead, I'm looking for something to make this method `$zone->users()->save($user)->save()` fail (taken from the test): I'd like to have a behavior very similar to what you get if you try to execute `$zone->users()->save($foo)->save()`, where $foo is not an instance of User, so it doesn't satisfy the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I see what you mean.. can you just [overwrite the save() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199756/laravel-4-trouble-overriding-models-save-method)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you check out "laravelbook/ardent"

https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent

This extension to the base Eloquent Model class does exactly what you want - it *automatically validates* before allowing a save.

Instead of manually calling `validate()`, you only call `save()` like this:

```
if ( $model->save() ) {
    echo "yay, it was all ok"
} else {
    echo "boo, we failed to save";
}
```

You create your validation rules in the same way as you would normally with Laravel, but Ardent is much smarter about handling them for you.