# Testing Model Save

Tags: unit-testing, model, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm trying to do a very basic `test`:

```
public function testUsernameIsRequired(){
  $user = new User;
  $user->email = "phil@ipbrown.com";

  // User should not save
  $this->assertFalse($user->save());
}
```

on the following `model`:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
  use SoftDeletingTrait;

  protected $fillable = array('email', 'username', 'password');

  public static $rules = array(
    'email'     =>  'required|min:3',
    'username'  =>  'required|min:3',
    'password'  =>  'required|min:3'
  );
}
```

According to my thinking (...yeah) this test should succeed, as a `User` model which gets saved without `required` fields doesn't actually save.

But this Model somehow does save, doesn't throw any errors and creates a completely empty User.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where/how are you calling the rules to 'save' the user against the validation? I dont see you validating anything.

Comment: I actually ain't because I couldn't find any documentation on that except for using 'Ardent' which I'd like to stay away from. So I don't have a starting point for self-validating Models and in the tutorials I read about model testing there wasn't any mentioning of it.

Comment: So how/why should the the save() fail? The rules are not being applied anywhere - so therefore the model SHOULD save in your test.

Comment: $rules is just something you made up - it wont work out of the box like that

Comment: Yeah that's what I was unclear about. $rules was stated in a Laravel Tutorial somewhere, I mistakingly thought it was a system-wide variable function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$rules is just something you made up - it wont work out of the box like that. You need to actually validate the models against the rules to enforce it on save.

[Laravel 4 - Trouble overriding model's save method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18199756/1317935) will do what you want without Ardent.