# Laravel - Automatically store history in column

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Can anyone help me to automatically save the history of all changed columns in a model to a history column in the same table as JSON format with column(s) name, original value, changed to, changed by?

I am looking for Traits like centralized function to use in all models.

I am using Laravel 8 with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I added the trait as follows: this trait should be included in the model. It will create an array and insert it into my model's JSON column. Additionally, I casted the history column as an array to store the array directly in the database.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait InsertHistory
{
    public static function bootHasHistory()
    {
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            $changes = [];
            foreach ($model->getDirty() as $key => $value) {
                $changes[$key] = [
                    'old' => $model->getOriginal($key),
                    'new' => $value,
                ];
            }
            if (!empty($changes)) {
                $history = $model->history;
                $history[] = $changes;
                $model->history = $history;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is maybe outdated since it is Laravel 4. But if it works, it is quickest way to insert log in DB wherever save() method is called for that model.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694395/13893004